C# WPF adding scrollviewer to grid breaking rows heights
When I add a ScrollViewer to the Grid, the height of the rows is broken as seen in the images. How can I fix it?
With ScrollViewer (bad):

Without ScrollViewer (good):

When I add height to the grid, it is fixed, but I do not want this. I want the grid to automatically grow and shrink when the window is resized.
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  >
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"></RowDefinition>
             <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         <Grid x:Name="MainMovieTvShow" Background="#000000" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         </Grid>

         <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
                 <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         </Grid>
     </Grid>
 </ScrollViewer>


maybe a minHeight might work

The ScrollViewer gives its children infinite space for measure/arrange passes, you may want to limit it. This can be done by binding child MaxHeight to ActualHeight of another control. And tricky part is to create such control (typically an invisible control, with only role to pass its actual dimensions after being properly layouted) or to deal with offsets and margins (can be done with converter, either specialized or reusable).

The size of the "content" (e.g. picture or movie) is typically "Auto"  (col and row); to render the actual size. Then you align things around that. Or you fix the content size; etc. Using "star" for everything will cause everything to fill any avaliable space.
